# I got wrong result when I enter second module in Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I'm creating GPA calculator using jquery mobile but I'm not getting the correct result after entering value of the second module for example when I insert Credits of the first module as 20 and the grade is "A" then I press Calculate button I get 4.00 which is fine till now but when again I insert 20 credits to the second module and the grade is "A" it doesn't give me the correct result it shows that the result 0.08 and it should be 4.00

here is my code with the script

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cal").click(function() { 
    var a = document.getElementById('name1').value
    eval(a)
    var b = $('#grade1 option:selected').val()
    var c = document.getElementById('name2').value
    eval(c)
    var d = $('#grade2 option:selected').val()
    var e = document.getElementById('name3').value
    eval(e)
    var f = $('#grade3 option:selected').val()
    var g = document.getElementById('name4').value
    eval(g)
    var h = $('#grade4 option:selected').val()
    var i = document.getElementById('name5').value
    eval(i)
    var j = $('#grade5 option:selected').val()
    var m1 = a * b;
    var m2 = c * d;
    var m3 = e * f;
    var m4 = g * h;
    var m5 = i * j;
    var total1 = m1 + m2 + m3 + m4 + m5;
    var total2 = a + c + e + g + i;
    var total3 = total1/total2
    var total3 = total3.toFixed(2);

    $('#res').val(total3);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="f"> <a data-iconpos="notext" data-role="button" data-icon="home" title="Home">Home</a>
    <h1>BENG GPA Calculator</h1>
    <form id="form">
      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li>Module 1</li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="name1">Credits:</label>
          <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
        </li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="grade1" class="select">Grade:</label>
          <select class="grade1" data-theme="f" id="grade1">
            <option value="-1">—</option>
            <option value="4">A</option>
            <option value="3.7">A-</option>
            <option value="3.3">B+</option>
            <option value="3">B</option>
            <option value="2.7">B-</option>
            <option value="2.3">C+</option>
            <option value="2">C</option>
            <option value="1.7">C-</option>
            <option value="1.3">D+</option>
            <option value="1">D</option
              >
            <option value="0">F</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>Module 2</li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="name2">Credits:</label>
          <input type="text" name="name2" id="name2" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
        </li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="grade2" class="select">Grade:</label>
          <select class="grade2" data-theme="f" id="grade2">
            <option value="-1">—</option>
            <option value="4">A</option>
            <option value="3.7">A-</option>
            <option value="3.3">B+</option>
            <option value="3">B</option>
            <option value="2.7">B-</option>
            <option value="2.3">C+</option>
            <option value="2">C</option>
            <option value="1.7">C-</option>
            <option value="1.3">D+</option>
            <option value="1">D</option>
            <option value="0">F</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>Module 3</li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="name3">Credits:</label>
          <input type="text" name="name3" id="name3" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
        </li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="grade3" class="select">Grade:</label>
          <select class="grade3" data-theme="f" id="grade3">
            <option value="-1">—</option>
            <option value="4">A</option>
            <option value="3.7">A-</option>
            <option value="3.3">B+</option>
            <option value="3">B</option>
            <option value="2.7">B-</option>
            <option value="2.3">C+</option>
            <option value="2">C</option>
            <option value="1.7">C-</option>
            <option value="1.3">D+</option>
            <option value="1">D</option>
            <option value="0">F</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>Module 4</li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="name4">Credits:</label>
          <input type="text" name="name4" id="name4" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
        </li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="grade4" class="select">Grade:</label>
          <select class="grade4" data-theme="f" id="grade4">
            <option value="-1">—</option>
            <option value="4">A</option>
            <option value="3.7">A-</option>
            <option value="3.3">B+</option>
            <option value="3">B</option>
            <option value="2.7">B-</option>
            <option value="2.3">C+</option>
            <option value="2">C</option>
            <option value="1.7">C-</option>
            <option value="1.3">D+</option>
            <option value="1">D</option>
            <option value="0">F</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>Module 5</li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="name5">Credits:</label>
          <input type="text" name="name5" id="name5" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
        </li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="grade5" class="select">Grade:</label>
          <select class="grade5" data-theme="f" id="grade5">
            <option value="-1">—</option>
            <option value="4">A</option>
            <option value="3.7">A-</option>
            <option value="3.3">B+</option>
            <option value="3">B</option>
            <option value="2.7">B-</option>
            <option value="2.3">C+</option>
            <option value="2">C</option>
            <option value="1.7">C-</option>
            <option value="1.3">D+</option>
            <option value="1">D</option>
            <option value="0">F</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="res">Result:</label>
          <input type="text" name="res" id="res" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
        </li>
        <li class="ui-body ui-body-b">
          <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
            <div>
              <button type="button" id="cal" name="cal" data-theme="f">Calculate</button>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-body ui-body-b">
          <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
            <div>
              <button type="reset" data-theme="d">Reset</button>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: What is the point of the `eval`s in there? They aren't actually doing anything.

Comment: yeah I know. I was trying to get the values in different ways when I was searching the whole day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Convert all the values into numbers through `parseFloat()`.
2. Use `0` as default value.
3. Remove useless `eval()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cal").click(function() { 
    var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById('name1').value) || 0
    var b = parseFloat($('#grade1 option:selected').val()) || 0
    var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById('name2').value) || 0
    var d = parseFloat($('#grade2 option:selected').val()) || 0
    var e = parseFloat(document.getElementById('name3').value) || 0
    var f = parseFloat($('#grade3 option:selected').val()) || 0
    var g = parseFloat(document.getElementById('name4').value) || 0
    var h = parseFloat($('#grade4 option:selected').val()) || 0
    var i = parseFloat(document.getElementById('name5').value) || 0
    var j = parseFloat($('#grade5 option:selected').val()) || 0
    var m1 = a * b;
    var m2 = c * d;
    var m3 = e * f;
    var m4 = g * h;
    var m5 = i * j;
    var total1 = m1 + m2 + m3 + m4 + m5;
    var total2 = a + c + e + g + i;
    var total3 = total1/total2
    var total3 = total3.toFixed(2);

    $('#res').val(total3);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="f"> <a data-iconpos="notext" data-role="button" data-icon="home" title="Home">Home</a>
    <h1>BENG GPA Calculator</h1>
    <form id="form">
      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li>Module 1</li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="name1">Credits:</label>
          <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
        </li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="grade1" class="select">Grade:</label>
          <select class="grade1" data-theme="f" id="grade1">
            <option value="-1">—</option>
            <option value="4">A</option>
            <option value="3.7">A-</option>
            <option value="3.3">B+</option>
            <option value="3">B</option>
            <option value="2.7">B-</option>
            <option value="2.3">C+</option>
            <option value="2">C</option>
            <option value="1.7">C-</option>
            <option value="1.3">D+</option>
            <option value="1">D</option
              >
            <option value="0">F</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>Module 2</li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="name2">Credits:</label>
          <input type="text" name="name2" id="name2" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
        </li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="grade2" class="select">Grade:</label>
          <select class="grade2" data-theme="f" id="grade2">
            <option value="-1">—</option>
            <option value="4">A</option>
            <option value="3.7">A-</option>
            <option value="3.3">B+</option>
            <option value="3">B</option>
            <option value="2.7">B-</option>
            <option value="2.3">C+</option>
            <option value="2">C</option>
            <option value="1.7">C-</option>
            <option value="1.3">D+</option>
            <option value="1">D</option>
            <option value="0">F</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>Module 3</li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="name3">Credits:</label>
          <input type="text" name="name3" id="name3" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
        </li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="grade3" class="select">Grade:</label>
          <select class="grade3" data-theme="f" id="grade3">
            <option value="-1">—</option>
            <option value="4">A</option>
            <option value="3.7">A-</option>
            <option value="3.3">B+</option>
            <option value="3">B</option>
            <option value="2.7">B-</option>
            <option value="2.3">C+</option>
            <option value="2">C</option>
            <option value="1.7">C-</option>
            <option value="1.3">D+</option>
            <option value="1">D</option>
            <option value="0">F</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>Module 4</li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="name4">Credits:</label>
          <input type="text" name="name4" id="name4" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
        </li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="grade4" class="select">Grade:</label>
          <select class="grade4" data-theme="f" id="grade4">
            <option value="-1">—</option>
            <option value="4">A</option>
            <option value="3.7">A-</option>
            <option value="3.3">B+</option>
            <option value="3">B</option>
            <option value="2.7">B-</option>
            <option value="2.3">C+</option>
            <option value="2">C</option>
            <option value="1.7">C-</option>
            <option value="1.3">D+</option>
            <option value="1">D</option>
            <option value="0">F</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>Module 5</li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="name5">Credits:</label>
          <input type="text" name="name5" id="name5" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
        </li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="grade5" class="select">Grade:</label>
          <select class="grade5" data-theme="f" id="grade5">
            <option value="-1">—</option>
            <option value="4">A</option>
            <option value="3.7">A-</option>
            <option value="3.3">B+</option>
            <option value="3">B</option>
            <option value="2.7">B-</option>
            <option value="2.3">C+</option>
            <option value="2">C</option>
            <option value="1.7">C-</option>
            <option value="1.3">D+</option>
            <option value="1">D</option>
            <option value="0">F</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="res">Result:</label>
          <input type="text" name="res" id="res" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
        </li>
        <li class="ui-body ui-body-b">
          <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
            <div>
              <button type="button" id="cal" name="cal" data-theme="f">Calculate</button>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-body ui-body-b">
          <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
            <div>
              <button type="reset" data-theme="d">Reset</button>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
```